# Thumbnail in dynamic listview not showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a dynamic list of posts showing post title and except but the post thumbnail isn't appearing. Below is the code I have tried using:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://howtodeployit.com/feed/?json=recentstories" ,
dataType: "json",
success: function (data){
   $.each(data.posts, function (key, val) {
     var title = $('<p/>', {'class' : 'ptitle', html: val.title});
     var excerpt = $('<p/>', {'class': 'pexcerpt' , html: val.excerpt});
     var thumb = $('<img />', {'class' : 'pthumb', html: val.thumbnail});
     var append = $('<li/>').append(thumb, title, excerpt);
     $('#postlist').append ($(rappend));
     $("#postlist").listview();
   });
});
```

Below is screenshot: As seen the image box is showing nothing but when I inspect that in firebug, I see the url link to the image

[image]

Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`var thumb = $('<img />', {'class' : 'pthumb', html: val.thumbnail});`

to

`var thumb = $('<img />', {'class' : 'pthumb', src: val.thumbnail});`

Information on the image element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img